# Angular2 ngClass function not working as expected

Tags: angular, ng-class

I have the following code

```
<a *ngFor="let slipStatus of slipStatuses; class="item striped"
     [ngClass]="{
       'green background': slipStatus.status === 'SOLD',
       'yellow background': slipStatus.status === 'IN PROGRESS',
       'blue background': slipStatus.status === 'DONE'
     }">
```

I would expect that if any of the expressions are true, both classes would get added. However, the 'background' class only gets added for the *last* ngClass rule.

So SOLD slips have class `green` only, IN PROGRESS have class `yellow` only and DONE slips correctly have both classes `blue background`.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you could provide a plunkr or example, but you are correct that if any of the expressions are true then the styles will be applied.

I think your issue may have to do with the CSS file. Remember that (assuming you have a flat css class heirarchy) the classes defined later are will have higher specificity and be applied over the other classes. Perhaps the styles "green" and "yellow" are overriding some properties of "background" class.

If that doesn't work I would also check this- What happens when you move around the properties in your NgClass object? For example, like this:

```
<a *ngFor="let slipStatus of slipStatuses; class="item striped"
     [ngClass]="{
       'blue background': slipStatus.status === 'DONE'
       'green background': slipStatus.status === 'SOLD',
       'yellow background': slipStatus.status === 'IN PROGRESS',
     }">
```